# Taylor series of $g(x)=f(cx)$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm having slight difficulties in understanding the Taylor polynomial for

$$g(x)=f(cx), \space c \in \mathbb{R}$$

The way I look at it is to start with:

$$T_{n, x_0}g(x)=\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{g^{(m)}(x_0)}{m!}(x-x_0)^m$$
$$=\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{f^{(m)}(c x_0)}{m!}(x-x_0)^m$$
$$=f(cx_0) + f'(cx_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(cx_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$$

But I'm having trouble understanding, what can I do with the derivatives $f'(cx_0)$, $f''(cx_0)$ ... ?

Like can I move the constant out? Because what I'm trying to show is that

$$T_{n, x_0} g(x) = T_{n, cx_0} f(cx)$$

---

OR do I have to "map" the $x_0$ so that

$$=\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{f^{(m)}(c x_0)}{m!}(x-x_0)^m$$

is actually

$$=\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{f^{(m)}(c x_0)}{m!}(x-cx_0)^m$$

because the $x_0$ has been shifted by $c$?

Comment: You forgot to apply the chain rule, $g^{(m)}(x_0) = f^{(m)}(cx_0)\cdot c^m$. Also, $$g(x) = f(cx) = f\bigl(cx_0 + (cx - cx_0)\bigr) = \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(m)}(cx_0)}{m!}(cx-cx_0)^m.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer What rule for chain rule for higher derivatives is that?

Comment: Just the ordinary chain rule, applied repeatedly. Let $\mu \colon x \mapsto cx$. Then $g = f\circ \mu$. Hence $g'(x) = f'(\mu(x))\cdot \mu'(x)$ by the chain rule. For the next derivative, we need the chain rule again, and also the product rule: $g''(x) = \bigl(f''(\mu(x))\cdot \mu'(x)\bigr)\cdot \mu'(x) + f'(\mu(x))\cdot \mu''(x)$. Oh, but $\mu'$ is constant, so $\mu'' \equiv 0$. Hence we don't actually need the product rule. Replacing $\mu'(x)$ with $c$, we have $g''(x) = f''(\mu(x))\cdot c^2$. Applying the chain rule to $g^{(m)}(x) = f^{(m)}(\mu(x))\cdot c^m$ gives the result for $m+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your Taylor series for $f$ is not correct.  To see this, put $y = cx$, and write out the Taylor series of $f$ w.r.t. $y$ at the point $y_{0} = cx_{0}$.  You get:
$$
f(y) = \sum_{m \geq 0} {f^{(m)} \over m!}(y_{0}) \; (y - y_{0})^{m}
= \sum_{m \geq 0} {f^{(m)} \over m!}(c x_{0}) \; (cx - cx_{0})^{m}.
$$
If I understand your question correctly, this should clear it up.

Comment: I doesn't clear, because if I know how the get the form you show, I'd have that form. But the problem was, how to get it. And @DanielFisher pointed out the solution, which was that I forgot chain rule.